# Importing values into workspace from a class in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, import, workspace

I have a question regarding MATLAB. I have class file where I can solve my problem with by simply defining the problem parameters in my script and call on a class in MATLAB to solve the problem with parameters that I provide. Now, the resulting variables that are computed by the class, how can I import them into the worskspace or display them within my MATLAB script without altering the class?

Class code

```html
classdef rankine
    % Rankine cycle class
    properties
        % Inlet properties
        mass_flow; % Mass flow of system (kg/s)
        Pboiler; % Boiler pressure (bar)
        superheat; % Boiler degrees superheat (C)
        isen_eff_turbine; % Turbine isentropic efficiency
        Pcond; % Condenser pressure (bar)
        subcooling; % Condenser subcooling
        
        % Calclated properties
        h_out_boiler; % Boiler outlet enthalpy (kJ/kg)
        s_out_boiler; % Boiler outlet entropy (kJ/kg-K)
        h_out_turbine; % Turbine outlet enthalpy (kJ/kg)
        s_out_turbine; % Turbine outlet entropy (kJ/kg-K)
        h_out_condenser; % Condenser outlet enthalpy (kJ/kg)
        s_out_condenser; % Condenser outlet entropy (kJ/kg-K)
        h_out_pump; % Pump outlet enthalpy (kJ/kg)
        s_out_pump; % Pump outlet entropy (kJ/kg-K)
        turbine_exh_quality; % Turbine exhaust quality
        T_boiler_out; % Boiler outlet temperature (C)
        T_turbine_out; % Turbine outlet temperature (C)
        T_condenser_out; % Condenser outlet temperature (C)
        T_pump_out; % Pump outlet temperature (C)
        Q_boiler; % Boiler Heat Rate (kW)
        W_turbine; % Turbine Work Rate (kW)
        Q_condenser; % Condenser Heat Rate (kW)
        W_pump; % Pump Work Rate (kW)
        Q_net; % Plant Net Heat Rate (kW)
        W_net; % Plant Net Work Rate (kW)
        plant_efficiency; % Plant Thermal Efficiency
        
    end
    
    methods % Methods for rankine class
        % Make constructor for the class
        function obj=rankine(mass_flow,Pboiler,superheat,isen_eff_turbine,Pcond,subcooling)
            
            % Enter system parameters
            obj.mass_flow=mass_flow;
            obj.Pboiler=Pboiler;
            obj.superheat=superheat;
            obj.isen_eff_turbine=isen_eff_turbine;
            obj.Pcond=Pcond;
            obj.subcooling=subcooling;
            
            % Calculate boiler outlet specific enthalpy and entropy
            if ~superheat % saturated vapor
                obj.T_boiler_out=XSteam('Tsat_p',Pboiler);
                obj.h_out_boiler=XSteam('hV_p',Pboiler);
                obj.s_out_boiler=XSteam('sV_p',Pboiler);
            else % Superheat
                obj.T_boiler_out=XSteam('Tsat_p',Pboiler)+superheat;
                obj.h_out_boiler=XSteam('h_pT',Pboiler,obj.T_boiler_out);
                obj.s_out_boiler=XSteam('s_pT',Pboiler,obj.T_boiler_out);
            end
            
            % Calculate turbine parameters
            h_out_s_turbine=XSteam('h_ps',Pcond,obj.s_out_boiler);
            obj.h_out_turbine=obj.h_out_boiler-isen_eff_turbine*(obj.h_out_boiler-h_out_s_turbine);
            obj.s_out_turbine=XSteam('s_ph',Pcond,obj.h_out_turbine);
            obj.turbine_exh_quality=XSteam('x_ph',Pcond,obj.h_out_turbine);
            obj.T_turbine_out=XSteam('Tsat_p',Pcond);
            obj.W_turbine=mass_flow*(obj.h_out_boiler-obj.h_out_turbine);
            
            % Calculate condenser parameters
            if ~subcooling % saturated liquid
                obj.h_out_condenser=XSteam('hL_p',Pcond);
                obj.s_out_condenser=XSteam('sL_p',Pcond);
                obj.T_condenser_out=obj.T_turbine_out;
                v=XSteam('vL_p',Pcond);
            else
                obj.T_condenser_out=obj.T_turbine_out-subcooling;
                obj.h_out_condenser=XSteam('h_pT',Pcond,obj.T_condenser_out);
                obj.s_out_condenser=XSteam('s_pT',Pcond,obj.T_condenser_out);
                v=XSteam('v_ph',Pcond,obj.h_out_condenser);
            end
            obj.Q_condenser=mass_flow*(obj.h_out_turbine-obj.h_out_condenser);
            
            % Calculate pump parameters
            obj.W_pump=(Pboiler-Pcond)*100*v*mass_flow;
            obj.h_out_pump=obj.h_out_condenser+(Pboiler-Pcond)*100*v;
            obj.s_out_pump=obj.s_out_condenser; % Isentropic case for now
            %obj.s_out_pump=XSteam('s_ph',Pboiler,obj.h_out_pump);
            obj.T_pump_out=XSteam('T_ph',Pboiler,obj.h_out_pump);
            
            % Calculate boiler heat rate
            obj.Q_boiler=(obj.h_out_boiler-obj.h_out_pump)*mass_flow;
            
            % Calcualte net work and heat rates
            obj.W_net=obj.W_turbine-obj.W_pump;
            obj.Q_net=obj.Q_boiler-obj.Q_condenser;
            obj.plant_efficiency=obj.W_net/obj.Q_boiler;
            
        end % End constructor
        
        function obj=update(obj,parameter_name,parameter_value)
            
            switch lower(parameter_name)
                case 'mass_flow'
                    obj.mass_flow=parameter_value;
                case 'pboiler'
                    obj.Pboiler=parameter_value;
                case 'superheat'
                    obj.superheat=parameter_value;
                case 'isen_eff_turbine'
                    obj.isen_eff_turbine=parameter_value;
                case 'pcond'
                    obj.Pcond=parameter_value;
                case 'subcooling'
                    obj.subcooling=parameter_value;
                otherwise
                    error('Parameter not modifiable.  Parameters to modify are mass_flow, Pboiler, superheat, isen_eff_turbine, Pcond, subcooling')
            end
            
            % Calculate boiler outlet specific enthalpy and entropy
            if ~obj.superheat % saturated vapor
                obj.T_boiler_out=XSteam('Tsat_p',obj.Pboiler);
                obj.h_out_boiler=XSteam('hV_p',obj.Pboiler);
                obj.s_out_boiler=XSteam('sV_p',obj.Pboiler);
            else % Superheat
                obj.T_boiler_out=XSteam('Tsat_p',obj.Pboiler)+obj.superheat;
                obj.h_out_boiler=XSteam('h_pT',obj.Pboiler,obj.T_boiler_out);
                obj.s_out_boiler=XSteam('s_pT',obj.Pboiler,obj.T_boiler_out);
            end
            
            % Calculate turbine parameters
            h_out_s_turbine=XSteam('h_ps',obj.Pcond,obj.s_out_boiler);
            obj.h_out_turbine=obj.h_out_boiler-obj.isen_eff_turbine*(obj.h_out_boiler-h_out_s_turbine);
            obj.s_out_turbine=XSteam('s_ph',obj.Pcond,obj.h_out_turbine);
            obj.turbine_exh_quality=XSteam('x_ph',obj.Pcond,obj.h_out_turbine);
            obj.T_turbine_out=XSteam('Tsat_p',obj.Pcond);
            obj.W_turbine=obj.mass_flow*(obj.h_out_boiler-obj.h_out_turbine);
            
            % Calculate condenser parameters
            if ~obj.subcooling % saturated liquid
                obj.h_out_condenser=XSteam('hL_p',obj.Pcond);
                obj.s_out_condenser=XSteam('sL_p',obj.Pcond);
                obj.T_condenser_out=obj.T_turbine_out;
                v=XSteam('vL_p',obj.Pcond);
            else
                obj.T_condenser_out=obj.T_turbine_out-obj.subcooling;
                obj.h_out_condenser=XSteam('h_pT',obj.Pcond,obj.T_condenser_out);
                obj.s_out_condenser=XSteam('s_pT',obj.Pcond,obj.T_condenser_out);
                v=XSteam('v_ph',obj.Pcond,obj.h_out_condenser);
            end
            obj.Q_condenser=obj.mass_flow*(obj.h_out_turbine-obj.h_out_condenser);
            
            % Calculate pump parameters
            obj.W_pump=(obj.Pboiler-obj.Pcond)*100*v*obj.mass_flow;
            obj.h_out_pump=obj.h_out_condenser+(obj.Pboiler-obj.Pcond)*100*v;
            obj.s_out_pump=XSteam('s_ph',obj.Pboiler,obj.h_out_pump);
            obj.T_pump_out=XSteam('T_ph',obj.Pboiler,obj.h_out_pump);
            
            % Calculate boiler heat rate
            obj.Q_boiler=(obj.h_out_boiler-obj.h_out_pump)*obj.mass_flow;
            
            % Calcualte net work and heat rates
            obj.W_net=obj.W_turbine-obj.W_pump;
            obj.Q_net=obj.Q_boiler-obj.Q_condenser;
            obj.plant_efficiency=obj.W_net/obj.Q_boiler;
            
        end % End update
        
        function plot_ts(obj) % Plots the t-s diagram of the process
            % Get the minimum and maximum pressures and temperatures
            Tmax=obj.T_boiler_out;
            Pmax=obj.Pboiler;
            Pmin=obj.Pcond;
            ts_diagram([Pmin Pmax],Tmax*1.5);
            title('T-s Diagram For Process')
            axesHandles=get(gcf,'Children');
            classHandles=handle(axesHandles);
            axes(classHandles(1))
            hold on
            
            % First draw the turbine process
            plot([obj.s_out_boiler obj.s_out_turbine],[obj.T_boiler_out obj.T_turbine_out],...
                'Linewidth',3,'Color','k')
     
            % Draw the condenser process
            sL=XSteam('sL_p',obj.Pcond); % Saturated liquid entropy
            s_line=[obj.s_out_turbine sL];
            T_line=[obj.T_turbine_out obj.T_turbine_out];
            if  (obj.subcooling~=0) % Subcooled
                s_line=[s_line obj.s_out_condenser];
                T_line=[T_line obj.T_condenser_out];
            end
            plot(s_line,T_line,'Linewidth',3)
            
            % Draw the pump process
            s_line=[obj.s_out_condenser obj.s_out_pump];
            T_line=[obj.T_condenser_out obj.T_pump_out];
            plot(s_line,T_line,'Linewidth',3,'Color',[0.5 0 0.5])
            
            % Draw the boiler process
            sL=XSteam('sL_p',obj.Pboiler);
            s_subcooled=linspace(obj.s_out_pump,sL,101);
            T_subcooled=arrayfun(@(s) XSteam('T_ps',obj.Pboiler,s), s_subcooled);
            sV=XSteam('sV_p',obj.Pboiler);
            TV=XSteam('Tsat_p',obj.Pboiler);
            s_line=[s_subcooled sV];
            T_line=[T_subcooled TV];
            if (obj.superheat>0)
                s_super=linspace(sV,obj.s_out_boiler,101);
                T_super=arrayfun(@(s) XSteam('T_ps',obj.Pboiler,s), s_super);
                s_line=[s_line s_super(2:end)];
                T_line=[T_line T_super(2:end)];
            end
            plot(s_line,T_line,'Linewidth',3,'Color','r')
            
            LH=legend('Turbine','Condenser','Pump','Boiler','Location','northwest');
            set(LH,'Color','w')
            
        end % End plot_ts
        
        function plot_mollier(obj)
            % Get extremities of operating points
            Phigh=obj.Pboiler;
            Plow=obj.Pcond;
            slow=obj.s_out_condenser;
            shigh=obj.s_out_boiler;
            hlow=obj.h_out_condenser;
            hhigh=obj.h_out_boiler;
            x_exhaust=obj.turbine_exh_quality;
            Thigh=obj.T_boiler_out;
            T_low=XSteam('T_ps',Phigh,shigh);
            
            pressures=[Plow/2 Plow Plow/4+Phigh/8 Plow/2+Phigh/4 Phigh/2 Phigh Phigh*1.5];
            temperatures=[Thigh-rem(Thigh,10)+10];
            entropies=[slow*0.8 shigh*1.2];
            qualities=min([0.7 x_exhaust-rem(x_exhaust,0.05)-0.05]):0.01:1;
            hrange=[hlow*0.8 hhigh*1.2];
            mollier(entropies,hrange,pressures,temperatures,qualities);
            title('Mollier diagram for process')
            axesHandles=get(gcf,'Children');
            classHandles=handle(axesHandles);
            axes(classHandles(1))
            hold on
            
            % Plot turbine line
            plot([obj.s_out_boiler obj.s_out_turbine],...
                 [obj.h_out_boiler obj.h_out_turbine],...
                 'Linewidth',3,'Color','k')
             
             % Plot condenser line
             scond=linspace(obj.s_out_turbine,obj.s_out_condenser,101);
             hcond=arrayfun(@(s) XSteam('h_ps',obj.Pcond,s),scond);
             plot(scond,hcond,'Linewidth',3,'Color','b')
             
             % Plot pump line
             spump=[obj.s_out_condenser obj.s_out_pump];
             hpump=[obj.h_out_condenser obj.h_out_pump];
             plot(spump,hpump,'Linewidth',3,'Color',[0.5 0 0.5])
             
             % Plot boiler line
             sboiler=linspace(obj.s_out_pump,obj.s_out_boiler,101);
             hboiler=arrayfun(@(s) XSteam('h_ps',obj.Pboiler,s),sboiler);
             plot(sboiler,hboiler,'Linewidth',3,'Color','r')
             
             LH=legend('Turbine','Condenser','Pump','Boiler','Location','northwest');
             set(LH,'Color','w')
             
        end % end plot_mollier
        
    end % End Methods
end % End rankine class
```

My script calling onto it.

```html
clc;
clear all;
close all;
import rankine

%Problem 1
mass_flow = 200;
Pboiler = 50;
superheat = 0;
isen_eff_turbine = 0.85;
Pcond = 1;
subcooling = 5;
problem1 = rankine(mass_flow, Pboiler, superheat, isen_eff_turbine, Pcond, subcooling)
```

The rankine class outputs solutions for each step such as

```html
h_out_boiler
s_out_boiler
h_out_turbine
s_out_turbine
```

Basically, I would like to take the variables the rankine class outputs and put them into the MATLAB workspace without modifying the rankine class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your script:

```
rankineOutput = struct(problem1) ;      %// convert the object into a structure

fldNames = fieldnames(rankineOutput) ;  %// get the field names of the structure

for iField = 1:numel(fldNames)
    varName = fldNames{iField} ;                            %// extract specific field name (just for the sake of clarity)
    assignin('base', varName , rankineOutput.(varName) ) ;  %// assign the value in the field to a variable with the same name in the base workspace
end
```

You might get a warning about the conversion of the object into structure but you can ignore it (it will not change the implementation of the class).

This will extract **all** the fields into variables in the base workspace. If you only want a subset you can use the same method but be more selective in which field you extract.

---

depending on your version of Matlab, you can even avoid the conversion to structure by calling the same directly on the object:

```
fldNames = fieldnames(problem1) ;  %// get the field names of the object

for iField = 1:numel(fldNames)
    varName = fldNames{iField} ;                       %// extract specific field name (just for the sake of clarity)
    assignin('base', varName , problem1.(varName) ) ;  %// assign the value in the field to a variable with the same name in the base workspace
end
```

Comment: Your answer looks interesting. I'm guessing it won't work if the internal object property changes right? I'm asking because the OP specified "for each step".

Comment: @krisdestruction, indeed. This will only work when the object execution is done. If you update or change the object, you will have to re-execute that to update your workspace.

Comment: @krisdestruction, That was a good point. But in this case it can still work, I checked the class implementation, and there is no internal iteration mechanism. The `update` method has to be called externally with some new/modified parameters, so the OP can just package the mini script above in a function `extract_to_workspace` and call it every time after he updates the object.

Comment: I did too, but wouldn't my solution be able to easily access the variables after instantiation without the `fieldnames` function?

Comment: That's kinda why I'm confused as to what OP meant by "step" since there's no step in the code, only the instantiation.

Comment: @krisdestruction, Sure. actually your solution is even more straightforward if he only wants to retrieve the 4 quoted fields. I gave my answer more as a generic option in case he wants more fields than he mentioned. (although the more I think about it, I'm under the impression that the OP would like something "automatic", kind of a `listener` thing, but since the class doesn't have any event, I don't see how it could be possible without modifying the class implementation).

Comment: ah excellent. I thought I was missing a large part of the question or missing something really obvious lol

Comment: well that's why I suggested inheriting the class if the variables are private, but if you manually update, you can just pull the data before/after you perform the update. Even if it's updated manually, inheriting the class would make it much easier to override existing functionality. I know because I do it with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the class constructor is `rankine(...)` and is called `rankine.m`. Put the file into your Matlab directory. Then, use the following line to instantiate it as you did.

```
problem1 = rankine(mass_flow, Pboiler, superheat, isen_eff_turbine, Pcond, subcooling)
```

After that line, the object `problem1` is now in your workspace. Since the properties are public, you can directly access them using the `.` operator. You can do this with other properties as well.

```
problem1.h_out_boiler
problem1.s_out_boiler
problem1.h_out_turbine
problem1.s_out_turbine
```

Comment: Ive added class code and my script into the main post.

Comment: @user2924294 Are you trying to get the outputs from the `update` function? Not sure if that's the "step" you're talking about.

Comment: @user2924294 It appears the properties you want are public so that should be easier. Can't you just grab the 4 variables you want every time `update` is called?

Comment: This worked great as well. I prefer to get all my data from that class into the workspace but this is a good alternate solution.

Comment: @user2924294 Yup well I guess the other solution would work for you. This is if you only want a few of the outputs :P I should note, if you're doing any operations with the numbers, it would be better if you feed the entire object into the function and access each variable at the time of execution instead of "loading everything into the workspace". It makes encapsulation and abstraction so much easier :)